# Can't find a library or function - Visual Basic 6

Tags: vba

I am a newbie in visual basic, when i tried to run this code,the above error pops up.I have declared an user defined function named initiative but for no reason the error pops up.

```
 Private Sub initiate()
For i = 0 To 2
    COURSE(i).Value = False
    SEM(i).Value = False
    If i <> 2 Then
    ODDEVEN(i).Value = False
    End If
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code is incomplete: what follows the `End If`?

Comment: what are `COURSE()`, `SEM()`= and `ODDEVEN()`?

Comment: "user defined function named initiative" does not match the function name in the code: `Private Sub initiate()`